# Issue with DPO training on OpenLLAMA 3B V2 model: "I am sorry I cannot reply to that question" response during inference

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

**Description**:

I am currently working on a project involving Direct Preference Optimization (DPO) training with the TRL library from Hugging Face. The goal is to align responses from the OpenLLAMA 3B V2 language model to preferences using a preferences dataset during training.

**Problem**:

I have successfully fine-tuned the model on instruction data, and the combined model with the RetrievalQA chain is working as expected. After DPO training, However, during inference, the model responds with "I am sorry I cannot reply to that question" for all questions, instead of selectively applying this response to specific cases.

**Details**:

-> The preferences dataset follows the format specified in the TRL library example link: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/main/examples/research_projects/stack_llama_2/scripts/dpo_llama2.py

->The Preference Dataset contains 180 records. Dataset is located at https://huggingface.co/datasets/Tatvajsh/DPO_AHS

-> The fine-tuning dataset contains 350 question-answer pairs.Finetuning Dataset Link:https://huggingface.co/datasets/Tatvajsh/AHS_Operations

-> DPO training is performed using the TRL library with a beta value of 0.1.

**Code**:

```py
!pip -q install datasets peft transformers trl accelerate bitsandbytes sentencepiece

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import os
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, Optional

import torch
from datasets import Dataset, load_dataset
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM, LoraConfig
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, HfArgumentParser, TrainingArguments

from trl import DPOTrainer
import pandas as pd
def dpo_data(train_or_val):
    df = pd.read_csv("//content/DPO_AHS_OPS - Copy.csv")
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df)

    original_columns = dataset.column_names

    def return_prompt_and_responses(samples):
        return {
            "prompt": [f"Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request. /n ### Instruction=>{prompt}. /n ### Response=>" for prompt in samples["prompt"]],
            "chosen": samples["chosen"],
            "rejected": samples["rejected"],
        }

    return dataset.map(
        return_prompt_and_responses,
        batched=True,
        remove_columns=original_columns,
    )

train_dataset = dpo_data("train")
train_dataset = train_dataset.filter(
    lambda x: len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["chosen"]) <= 512
    and len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["rejected"]) <= 512
)
train_dataset

train_dataset[150]

# 1. load a pretrained model
model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "Tatvajsh/AHS_OPS-WPCS_ALPHA_V_1.0",
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    load_in_4bit=True,
)
model.config.use_cache = False

model_ref = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        "Tatvajsh/AHS_OPS-WPCS_ALPHA_V_1.0",
        low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        load_in_4bit=True,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2",use_fast=False)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

    train_dataset = dpo_data("train")
    train_dataset = train_dataset.filter(
        lambda x: len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["chosen"]) <= 1600
        and len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["rejected"]) <= 1600
    )
    # eval_dataset = dpo_data("val")
    # eval_dataset = eval_dataset.filter(
    #     lambda x: len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["chosen"]) <= 256
    #     and len(x["prompt"]) + len(x["rejected"]) <= 256
    # )

    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        per_device_train_batch_size=4,
        max_steps=20,
        logging_steps=1,
        save_steps=5,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
        gradient_checkpointing=True,
        learning_rate=2e-4,
        evaluation_strategy="steps",
        eval_steps=5,
        output_dir="dpo_AHS_OPS_WPCS",
        report_to="none",
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
        warmup_steps=2,
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
        fp16=True,
        remove_unused_columns=False,
        run_name="dpo_llama2",
    )

    peft_config = LoraConfig(
        r=8,
        lora_alpha=16,
        lora_dropout=0.05,
        target_modules=['base_layer','gate_proj', 'v_proj','up_proj','down_proj','q_proj','k_proj','o_proj'],
        bias="none",
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
    )

model_ref

dpo_trainer = DPOTrainer(
        model,
        model_ref,
        args=training_args,
        beta=0.1,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=train_dataset,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        max_prompt_length=512,
        max_length=512,
    )

# 6. train
dpo_trainer.train()
dpo_trainer.save_model("dpo_AHS_OPS_WPCS")

# 7. save
output_dir = os.path.join("dpo_AHS_OPS_WPCS", "final_checkpoint")
dpo_trainer.model.save_pretrained(output_dir)

dpo_trainer.model.push_to_hub("Tatvajsh/dpo_AHS_OPS_WPCS_v3.0")
```

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect the model to provide "I am sorry I cannot reply to that question" responses for specific questions based on the preferences dataset during inference.

**Images of Working And Not working Tests:**
1)An example where The expected Behavior is maintained by the Model
[image]

2)An example where The expected Behavior is maintained by the Model
[image]

3)Failed Test where The expected answer is not given by the model
[image]
**Request for Help:**

I am seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue and selectively apply the desired response during inference. Any insights, suggestions, or examples related to DPO training with OpenLLAMA 3B V2 would be greatly appreciated.

**Inference Code**

```py
    import os
    import torch
    from transformers import (
        AutoModelForCausalLM,
        AutoTokenizer,
        BitsAndBytesConfig,
        HfArgumentParser,
        TrainingArguments,
        pipeline,
        logging,
    )
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            "openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2",
            device_map="auto",
            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
            load_in_4bit=True
    
        )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("openlm-research/open_llama_3b_v2",trust_remote_code=True,use_fast=False,padding=256,truncation=256)
    from peft import PeftModel, PeftConfig
    model1 = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id,device_map="auto")
    pipe = pipeline("text-generation",
                    model=model1,
                    tokenizer= tokenizer,
    #                 torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                    device_map="auto",
                    max_new_tokens = 512,#256,512
                    do_sample=True,
                    top_k=30,
                    num_return_sequences=1,
                    temperature=0.30,
    #                 max_seq_len=2000,
                    max_length=2000,
                    # eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
                    # use_cache=True,
                    repetition_penalty=1.2,
                    # output_scores=True,
                    # return_dict_in_generate=True,
                    # num_beams=15,
                    )
    
    from langchain import HuggingFacePipeline
    from langchain import PromptTemplate,  LLMChain
    from langchain import PromptTemplate
    llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline = pipe, model_kwargs = {'temperature':0.30,'repetition_penalty':1.3,"num_beams":10})
    custom_prompt_llmchain="""
     Below is an instruction that describes a task. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.
        ### Instruction:
        {question}
        ### Response:
        """
    
    
    def set_custom_prompt_1():
        """
        Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vectorstore
        """
        prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_llmchain,
                                input_variables=["question"])
        return prompt
    #Loading the model
    from langchain import PromptTemplate,  LLMChain
    
    def create_chain():
        llm_chain = LLMChain(
                llm=llm,
                prompt=set_custom_prompt_1(),
                verbose=True,
            )
        return llm_chain
    chain1=create_chain()
    chain1("are you sure that you can tell us more about how to apply for US visa?")
    chain1("Tell me a funny Joke.")
```

Comment: Can you please post the inference code as well? Also, please avoid screenshots because every time a screenshot of text is uploaded on SO, [a kitten dies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Sorry about uploading the Pictures and I am adding the Inference code as well, Thank you